# file_get_contents: Unable to set local cert chain file

Tags: php, ssl, zend-framework, composer-php, satis

We're using composer to upgrade dependencies with Satis. After a recent server upgrade we were unable to do so. Narrowing down possible causes, we've discovered, that file_get_contents php function fails while trying to establish an ssl connection.

We're using the following script to test our ssl:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://satis.work.com/packages.json';
$contextOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer'      => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'local_cert'       => '/home/work/.ssl/deployer.pem',
    ]
];
$sslContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $sslContext);
echo $result, "\n";
```

This is thrown:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to set local cert chain file `/home/work/.ssl/deployer.pem'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in /home/omlook/test-ssl.php on line 12
>   PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/work/test-ssl.php on line 12
>   PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://satis.work.com/packages.json): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/work/test-ssl.php on line 12

It is definitely not a problem with rights or file ownership, script can read .pem just fine. What's bewildering about this, is how the *exact* same script and .pem key work just fine in my local environment, and version differences aren't that significant, it seems.

Local environment:

> PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Server:

> PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2017 10:07:42) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.7-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>
> OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

Comment: have you tried to verify you certificate? should be something like this "openssl verify -verbose /home/work/.ssl/deployer.pem"

Comment: Verify works fine:

COMMAND(openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /home/work/.ssl/ca.pem /home/work/.ssl/deployer.pem)
RESULTS IN (/home/work/.ssl/deployer.pem: OK)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen only if you leave out the cleartext-metadata (Issuer, Validity, etc.) before the "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" part in the PEM file. For newer builds of PHP (including 7.0) this part seems to be mandatory now. I haven't found out more so far, but my guess is, this is rather an openssl-issue.
Renewing the certificate, including the metadata-part generated by openssl, solved the Problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the same problem for me.** It seems that cleartext metadata doesn't matter.
Similar code worked for me on php 7.0 with openssl 1.1.0j and was broken on php 7.3 with openssl 1.1.1c - I've got the same error text.
Adding cleartext metadata didn't help me. Adding `cafile` context parameter with current ca certificate didn't helped me too.

When I tried to make the same request with curl, I've got error:

```
curl -k --cert cert.pem https://myservice.com/soap/ShopService/
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

**So I find existing old client certificate was signed with weak sha1WithRsaEncryption algorithm.** 
Private key was 2048 bit lenth - it's ok (if you have 1024 bits - it's not safe now and you need a new longer key also)

**I've reissued my client certificate with actual sha256 hash**  (openssl option -sha256). My CA certificate had the same weak hash sha1 but it was not necessary to change it, just client certificate. Commands:

```
# here: 
# cert.pem - my old client certificate with private key
# ca.pem - service's current CA certificate for signing client certificates with it's private key
# cert2.pem - my new working client certificate with the same old private key
#
# make new certificate request from current client certificate
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in cert.pem -out cert2.csr -signkey cert.pem -sha256

# make new certificate
openssl x509 -req -in cert2.csr -out cert2.pem -CA ca.pem -sha256 -days 730 -set_serial 0x51ca170d

# append private key
openssl rsa -in cert.pem >> cert2.pem
```

Hours of pain and now it's ok )
Seems that php sends incorrect error message for this error.