# Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to set local cert chain file

Tags: php, ssl

I have next code:

```
$stream_context_create = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert'        => $ssl_key2,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $stream_context_create);
```

But when I trying to run it I receive an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to set local cert chain file `/tmp/1.pem'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in /srv/index.php

I work on PHP7.0 and OpenSSL 1.1.0f

url works in browser. but can't get content from code.

Whats wrong?

Comment: is it a self signed cert? and has you rights for `tmp` ?

Comment: Yes, it is self signed and yes it exist in system tmp directory.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208159/file-get-contents-unable-to-set-local-cert-chain-file maybe the answer can help you